# Using JavaScript RegExp to valid email. Regex special characters not working

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, email

I've got this JavaScript function:

```
function emailaddresscheck() {
        var emailregex = new RegExp("[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)");
        var emailstring = $("#email-address").val();
        if (emailregex.test(emailstring)) {
            $("#email-address-check").fadeIn(100);
            return true;
        }
        else if ($("#email-address").val().length <= 5) {
            $("#email-address-check").fadeOut(100);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The `if` condition is firing if I have a simple string in the RegExp constructor but this more complex regex isn't working.

Where am I going wrong?

UPDATE:

This is the finished working code:

```
function emailaddresscheck() {
        var emailregexp = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.(?:[A-Za-z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)$");
        var emailstring = $("#email-address").val();
        if (emailregexp.test(emailstring) === true) {
            $("#email-address-check").fadeIn(100);
            return true;
        }
        else if (emailregexp.test(emailstring) === false) {
            $("#email-address-check").fadeOut(100);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post some input that isn't working please?

Comment: I can't because with this regex the JavaScript popup box won't open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a regex with the `RegExp` constructor you *need* to double escape special characters since they are inside a string.

```
new RegExp("[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)");
                                     -^-
```

Or just use a literal regex:

```
/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)/
```

Comment: Good answer, yours is better. I'm deleting mine.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Working great now!